# What is the difference between writing this code with and without class?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

so I've been getting confused about this particular issue, hopefully someone more experienced can help me out on this.

Why does this work:

This will add the value as a key, and the value of the key to true. So if you say something like this

```
const mySet = new Set()
mySet.add("hello")
```

it will return this: `{hello: true}`.

But if I do something like this outside ES6 classes, so more like this:

```
const car = {
  color: "red"
}

car[built] = 2019
```

This will say built is `undefined`, is this only usable in ES6 classes?

Comment: try `car["built"] = 2019;`

Comment: `built` is considered a variable if you do not specify otherwise by enclosing the word within inverted commas. [check this out](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)

Answer (score 1):

`car[built] = 2019` built is an undefined variable

Change it to `car["built"] = 2019` or `car.built = 2019`

```
var car = {};
var built = "some key";
car[built] = true;
```

then car is `{"some key": true}`

Answer (score 0):

It works in the class syntax as you have defined a method that accepts a variable that is used as a key, and thus successfully creates a key in the object.

In the `car[built]` syntax it considers `built` here as a variable and thus fails in this case.

Whenever defining a key using `obj[key]` syntax, the key should either be a value or a string.